# Can I create reusable test steps in nightwatch.js?

Tags: node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

I am looking to create reusable components within my `nightwatch.js` tests.

*ie. login to the web app, logout of the web app*

What is the best method / pattern for creating these steps in a reusable way?

Comment: I believe page objects and  custom commands both provide reusability. For reusable components such as login, logout, custom commands can be used.  But for creating truly elaborate end to end test scenarios page objects would be the way to go, becuase it's likely that there are repeated test steps as you move through the application.

Comment: In case you don't have to use the hopeless Nightwatch, Python/behave has what you need - "execute_steps" command.

Answer (score 30):

You can create custom commands for that: http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#writing-custom-commands

1. in nightwatch.json specify the path to the folder that will contain your custom command file
2. create a js file and name it how your custom command should be names (ie login.js)
3. write the code you need:

```js
exports.command = function(username, password) {
    
    this
        .waitForElementVisible('#password', 4000)
        .setValue('#password', password)
        .waitForElementVisible('#username', 1000)
        .setValue('#username', username)
        .waitForElementVisible('#sign_in', 1000)
        .click('#sign_in')
        .waitForElementVisible('h1.folder-title', 10000)
        
        return this;
};
```

4. use the custom command in your test:

```js
.login("your_username", "your_password")
```

Comment: It's best to not just link to an answer, but to try to write a concise version of the answer here that will not succumb to linkrot etc.

Comment: This answer is so much simpler than the current documentation.

Answer (score 4):

This is typically done with page objects.
http://nightwatchjs.org/guide#page-objects

Then you can just

```
var myPage = client.page.myPage();

myPage.navigate()
  .assert.title('MyPage')
  .login('foo', 'bar)
  .assert.displayName('foo');
```

Answer (score -1):

To add to the previous answer, you can also create custom assertions and reporters in addition to commands.

The [Nightwatch Guide](http://nightwatchjs.org/guide) has more information on customization and extending Nightwatch.